# Associative law with negative sign

Tags: group-theory, arithmetic, binary-operations

We know that $a+b+c$ is meaningful for, say, the group $\left( \mathbb{Z}%
,+\right) $. Since for any $b,c$, we must have $b^{-1},c^{-1}$, therefore $%
a+b^{-1}+c^{-1}$ has to be meaningful, too, but we know that $a-b-c$ is
meaningless because the associative law fails. What's going on?

Comment: Excellent question.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression $a - b - c$ is not meaningless, it just needs to be interpreted in the correct way. As you rightly point out, subtraction is not associative, so we need to specify whether $a - b - c$ means $(a - b) - c$ or $a - (b - c)$. As you are probably aware, the expression $a - b - c$ refers to the former.

The fact that subtraction and division are not associative, is precisely why we have PEMDAS/BEDMAS/other variants which describe in which order to perform operations; note, these rules tell you that $a - b - c$ means $(a - b) - c$ and not $a - (b - c)$. This allows us to use expressions with many binary operations and no parentheses, yet still have a well-defined meaning.

Comment: So, it's just a matter of convention? I thought there'd be a more rigorous explanation.